# Bulk insertion in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Following PHP code is working fine when only ONE set of array values in POST ie, on index value 0...When index value is greater than one, duplicate entries are getting inserted into the table..please help...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO js (s_name, s_age, s_marks, s_school) VALUES ";
foreach($_POST as $objResult)
    {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($objResult as $Result){
        $i++;
        if($i>1)// add ',' after first set of values in INSERT..
        {
            $sql .= ",";
        }
        $name = $Result['sname']; 
        $age = $Result['age']; 
        $mark = $Result['mark']; 
        $school = $Result['school']; 
        $sql .= "('".$name."','" .$age."','".$mark."','" .$school."')";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
    }}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$sql .= "(" . implode(', ', $Result) . ")";` do, without all the silly itterating you've got going on?

Comment: You can also try setting a unique constraint as a quick fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggessions. And I changed my code as following..

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO js (s_name, s_age, s_marks, s_school) VALUES ";
foreach($_POST['student'] as $Result)
 {
        $name = $Result['sname']; 
        $age = $Result['age']; 
        $mark = $Result['mark']; 
        $school = $Result['school']; 
        $sql .= "('".$name."','" .$age."','".$mark."','" .$school."'),";

    }
$sql = rtrim($sql,",");
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can completely eliminate any issues with all of that iterating you have going on by doing something like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $objResult) {
    foreach($objResult as $Result) {
        $sql .= "(" . implode(', ', $Result) . "),";
    }
}
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```

And now do you notice how I moved the query out of your loops? That makes sure that you run it properly and not on every iteration (loop) of the data.

---

Here is a working [**`Example`**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#ZokcNXGVT) (*You will have to press `ctrl` + `enter` to run the code*)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the

```
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```

out of the inner loop, you are not clearing the string, so it will keep adding in the entries added already.

Answer (score 0):

you can change code like this

```html
foreach($_POST as $objResult) {
    foreach($objResult as $Result) {
        $sql .= "(" . implode(', ', $Result) . "),";
    }
}
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```